# get facebook user uid with codeigniter

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

I have facebook SDK with my codeigniter, and I want to get the user facebook uid.

So I have something like this:

```
$this->fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id'                => MY APP ID,
        'app_secret'            => THE SECRET CODE,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
        ]);

$helper = $this->fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken(); 

$this->facebook->token = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];

$res = $this->facebook->fb->get('/me', $this->facebook->token);
$user = $res->getGraphObject();
echo $user->getProperty( 'id' );
```

now it does gives me an id, though it's not the user uid, I think it's the id of the user, when he registred to my app.
I can print hes user name and rest of his public data, but I want the uid.

any ideas?

*using codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Read about "App Scoped IDs" in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

I guess that´s the ID you get, it´s perfectly fine. You can´t get the "real" (or "global") ID anymore, but it´s not neccessary anyway. Just use the App Scoped ID for user identification.

Comment: then how can I then check who is the user or get he's real uid?

Comment: what exactly do you want to check? the app scoped id will stay the same in one app, so you can detect returning users with it. again, you can´t get his "real" id anymore, and you don´t need it anyway.